# Connect and diconnect to SQL Server 2008R2 using a query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to run a proc on several servers to gather statistics and would like to streamline the process to run in 1 job, rather than several.

Is there a way to connect to a server and disconnect using an SQL query ?

For example, if my server's name is S1, I'd like to do something similar to this:

```
Connecet S1
Go
Use DB1
Go
exec sp_xxxxx
Go
Disconnect S1
Go
Connect S2
Go
Use DB2
exec sp_xxxxx
Go
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Openrowset method in SQL server like below

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Seattle1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT GroupName, Name, DepartmentID
      FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department
      ORDER BY GroupName, Name') AS a;
```

ref [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

or use Linked Servers method
see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) or [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)